# ¿Como agregar una nueva linea en un DataGridView con Doble Click C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quisiera agregar una nueva linea en un `DataGridView`, dando doble click.
Pero no he logrado que agregue la nueva linea.
Para esto utilizo el evento:

```
private void Partes_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ }
```

`Partes` es el nombre de mi `DataGridView` en el código.

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable datos = new DataTable();
    public string datos = "";
    public string descripcion = "";
    public string material = "";
    public string SN = "";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        crearDatatable();
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        InitializeDataGridView();
    }
    private void InitializeDataGridView()
    {
        try
        {
            //DataGridView1.DataSource="";
            dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al iniciarGrid");
        }
    }
    public bool crearDatatable()
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Datos";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Descripcion";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Material";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Numero de Serie";

        return true;
    }
    //estos datos se mandan a un xml.
    private void getData(int e)
    {
        datos = dataGridView1.Rows[e].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        descripcion = dataGridView1.Rows[e].Cells[1].ToString();
        material = dataGridView1.Rows[e].Cells[2].ToString();
        SN = dataGridView1.Rows[e].Cells[3].ToString();
        return;

    }
    private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeDataGridView();
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {

        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0];
        }
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    private void Partes_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el código que utilizas para crear la nueva linea? Ahí solo has puesto la cabecera que invoca el método de doble click.

Comment: La verdad hasta ahí he podido llegar, se que con eso puedo invocar al método, pero por mas que he intentado utilizarlo, he tenido muchas complicaciones. Los se, me hace falta experiencia, soy nuevo en esto.

Answer (score 0):

Pero como estas llenando el datagrid?
Suponiendo que estas utilizando un Datatable para llenar el Datagrid
arias así

```
private void Partes_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{ 
    //agregas fila
    DataTable dt = NombreTuDataTable;
    DataRow row= dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    //cargas los datos
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

}
```

**NombreTuDataTable** es el nombre del Datatable con el Cual llenas tu DataGrid.

En mi blog tengo un articulo donde agrego una nueva fila para sumar los datos de una columna
[SUMAR COLUMNAS DATAGRIDVIEW USANDO LINQ](http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/2012/08/sumar-columnas-datagridview-usando-linq.html)

Comment: public bool crearDatatable()
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Datos";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Descripcion";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Material";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Numero de Serie";
            
            return true;
        }

Comment: private void getData(int e)
        {
            datos = dataGridView1.Rows[e].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            descripcion = dataGridView1.Rows[e].Cells[1].ToString();
            material = dataGridView1.Rows[e].Cells[2].ToString();
            SN = dataGridView1.Rows[e].Cells[3].ToString();
            return;

        }

Comment: Lo siento tengo que enviarlo por partes

Comment: Listo ya lo pude subir completo

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses los eventos del `DataGridView`.
Si lo que quieres es que cuando hagas doble click en el area gris del `DataGridView` por ejemplo(entre otros muchos eventos doble click)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usa este evento:

```
private void DataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0);
}
```

Comment: Lo añadí pero no me funciona

Comment: Yo lo he ejecutado y si que me funciona. Que error te da? Obviamente si tienes otros eventos sobre el click a lo mejor se vuelve un poco loco

Comment: si efectivamente tenia otros eventos que estaban estorbando, ya funciono gracias

Comment: @JAguilar si mi respuesta te ha sido util, no te olvides votarla y marcarla como respuesta a tu pregunta :)